# Can we add 'Vote History' back to our Ask Ubuntu profile page?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, voting

I want to view my voting history on my profile page here on Ask Ubuntu. How do I do this?

Judging from [this Meta Stack Overflow question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41932/can-i-see-my-vote-history), this functionality existed and was removed '[for some reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/41935/176211)'. Digging further into the search results, I see [this related question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14610/where-did-the-votes-tab-go/14625#14625), with many votes in favor, and many down-votes for the statement '[We don't think this tab is useful any more](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/14625/176211)'.

**Can this feature be restored, or a workaround provided, even if it is only for askubuntu.com?**

Comment: You do realise that Jeff's post predate this site's existence by an entire year? So this feature had never existed for Ask Ubuntu. Anyway, you're never going to get features like this for one site only - it has to be network wide, which means this belongs on MSO, where it is a dupe to that question you already linked to.

Comment: @YiJiang Thanks for clarifying the timeline of events. Nothing in the question title or body conflicts with it, so I'm going to leave things as-is. I'm looking for a workaround or a site-specific solution. If these are not technically possible, have a go at the answer or flag and link to any dupes.

Comment: @YiJiang Note that [posting general feature requests or bug reports on a child meta is absolutely fine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89228/which-meta-am-i-supposed-to-post-on/89232#89232).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like it is back now. :)

Read waffle's answer on Meta StackOverflow: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130380/177471

Comment: If this feature is now back on all Stack Exchange sites, then maybe my question can be deleted as 'too localized' or something like that?